# Angular is getting wrong timestamp

Tags: angular, date, timestamp

i have issues with wrong dates between backend and frontend.

The TimeStamp is saved in the DB like this: **15.11.2022, 08:45:00** (Datatype: Timestamp)

The Frontend is getting this Date: **2022-11-15T07:45:00.000+00:00** (Datatype: Date)

My TimeZone is GMT+1. What i need to configure that i get the right date?

Comment: More context please, how do you get the data, where do you use it, how do you use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a JavaScript Timestamp equivalent. Consider using the Angular Date Pipe

```html
<ng-container>{{yourTimestampVariable | date: 'shortDate'}}</ng-container>
```

Documentation on that can be found here: https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe

Comment: Thank you this solved my problem. This: start | date: "HH:mm" fixxed the hour difference. Now i got the right hour displayed.